# Migrate/Extend raid1 volume to larger disks on Dell PowerEdge 2950 with perc 6/i - OMSA

Tags: dell-poweredge, raid1, dell-perc, dell-openmanage

I have a dell PowerEdge 2950 with perc 6/i running raid1, there were 2 250GB drives in which have been replaced (one at a time) with 1TB drives.

So now I have the a virtual disk that is 232.25GB and 698.75GB (Free) that I would like to extend/reconfigure the virtual drive to utilize.

From what I understand my plan was to do the following:

- Take a full backup. **DONE!**
- Replace the drives one by one and wait for a rebuild to complete.
  **DONE!**
- Use Dell OpenManage Server Administrator to extend the size of the
  physical RAID 1 volume on the disk from 232.25GB to full 1TB, using
  the reconfigure option  **Here is where I'm running into an issue**
- Extend the partitions in Windows...

When running the Reconfigure it only has Raid0 as an option with the 464.50GB min/max Listed... I am not sure whats going on here.

Here are screens of the options:
[omsareconfig](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4OoV.jpg)

Any help getting this sorted would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is exactly why I hate non-standardized hardware raids. I ran into this issue before (on a Windows Server 2008 I didn't install) and it wasn't possible to resize the RAID 1 with the Dell software (which I find is ridiculous). I read some guides on it but found no solution that didn't have the possibiliy of complete data loss. In the end I ended up with a new install. Check this out: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28446937/Expanding-a-RAID-1-on-Dell-poweredge-resize-partitions-OpenManage-Open-Manage.html

Comment: I agree that it's ridiculous not to have this capability - thankfully this limitation was short-lived. That old PERC model only supported expansion via adding spindles, but the H700 and newer all support expansion to free disk space as you were wanting to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly expand the virtual disk with a perc6. Double check your backup and if it is fine, you can:

- Delete the virtual disk
- Create a new virtual disk, using RAID 1
- **Do not initialize the disk**
- **Do not set advanced options**

It should have all of the space available now with your old data intact.

Comment: I'm assuming since the raid VD contains the OS I will need to bring the Machine down and do the delete and recreation in the raid BIOS? Since the machine would crash if this was attempted in OMSA no? I was under the impression that the PERC 6/i could do this from everything I read.